# How to store large form in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a large form (~150 inputs) and a classic Controller (with create/store methods). Also I'm using validation rules.

**Store method:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'        => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+$/u|min:2|max:50',
        'phone'       => 'required|digits_between:9,10',
        'description' => 'required|min:20|max:500',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $request['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
    Profile::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('admin.profile.index');
}
```

In this case, the form doesn't store any data...

When I tried to decrease input numbers (from 150 to 30) - data was stored successfully!

After that, I increase "php_memory_limit","max_input_vars" etc. but problem wasn't fixed.

Please help to find best way to store large forms.

**UPD:**

Form stores successfully without validation...
I tried to set just one simple rule - "required", but problem the problem has not disappeared

Comment: What is the approximate size of your input (in bytes)?

Comment: what inside you model?

Comment: and you can use `$request->validate([RULES])` to remove  `if ($validator->fails())`

Comment: Are you getting an error, a white page or is it just returning without saving?

Comment: @Rwd, just returning without saving

Comment: try to `dd` the `$request`, and store the new created `Profile` in a  variable and `dd` it.

Comment: @autumnrustle, I tried both ways

Comment: @EugeniyI what inside you model? Validation now is not important. You can remove it for now.

Comment: @apokryfos 95% just checkboxes (1 or 0)

Comment: Try running `dd($validator->errors());` inside the if statement before returning the redirect. What do you get?

Comment: @Rwd,  `dd($validator->errors());` result -  http://joxi.ru/L21GBB3igwjlKr?d=1

Comment: @autumnrustle, validation is important because, as it turned out, without validation everything works

Comment: The reason it isn't storing an data is because the validation is failing. According to the picture above, the `name`, `phone`, and `description` field are apparently missing.

Comment: @Rwd true, but why is it returning without any messages when the form has 150 inputs and return with error messages then the form has just 30 inputs?

Comment: I'm confused, so you have number of input fields or quantity of data or both ?, because if you have one large form then you can split it into two or more, if you have quantity more then you need to set max value than can be passed via post request.

Answer (score 0):

- You can increase `max_input_vars` value in the `php.ini` file
- or change your UI and **split inputs on multiple pages**

Comment: As I mentioned, I did it.

Now max_input_vars = 10000

Comment: @Eugene can you change the input and split it to multiple parts?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but problem left when I changed

`return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);` to

`return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->messages());`